# Como ler uma quantidade aleatória de inteiros em C?

Tags: c

Eu preciso criar uma forma de ler inteiros em um mesmo input, sendo que a quantidade de inteiros inseridos é aleatória toda vez que se executa o programa.

Eu tentei realizar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    long int numero, i, vetor[100000];

    i = 0;
    while(scanf("%li", &numero) != EOF)
        vetor[i++] = numero;

    while(i > 0)
        printf("%li ", vetor[i--]);

    return 0;
}
```

Entretanto, em uma máquina, o 1º while nunca termina. E em outra máquina, obtenho um segmentation fault. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O teu problema e no uso do `scanf()`

```
while(scanf("%li", &numero) != EOF)
```

O valor que o `scanf()` devolve normalmente corresponde ao numero de atribuicoes efectuadas (no teu caso esse valor e `1` porque so ha uma atribuicao a variavel `numero`).

Nota que um `scanf()` com mais que uma atribuicao pode devolver um numero inferior sem ser erro

```
chk = scanf("%d%d%d", &um, &dois, &tres);
if (chk == 3) /* 3 atribuicoes */;
if (chk == 2) /* 2 atribuicoes: `tres` nao foi atribuido */;
if (chk == 1) /* 1 atribuicao: apenas `um` foi atribuido */;
if (chk == 0) /* nenhuma atribuicao */;
if (chk == EOF) /* erro de leitura */;
```

No teu exemplo acima nao deves testar o valor devolvido pelo `scanf()` com `EOF`, mas sim com `1`

```
while(scanf("%li", &numero) == 1)
```

Comment: Tinha esquecido de explicar que CTRL+Z gera o EOF... Boa resposta +1.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz algumas alterações pequenas no seu código e testei utilizando <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> para parar a leitura dos inteiros, funcionou perfeitamente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    long int numero, i = 0, vetor[100000];

    while(scanf("%li", &numero) != EOF)
    {
        if (i == 99999)     //caso o vetor chegue ao seu limite a leitura encerra.
        {
            printf("Limite do vetor atingido!\n");
            break;
        } 
        else 
        {
            vetor[i++] = numero;
        }
    }

    while(i > 0)
        printf("%li ", vetor[--i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Faça o teste utilizando esse código, se der algum problema me avise nos comentários que vou buscar resolve-lo. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ok, funcionou perfeitamente utilizando o Ctrl + Z. No entanto, eu queria entender porque o 1º while não pára quando chega ao fim do input.

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer dizer com fim do input... Seria no fim dos 100000 slots do vetor? Pois quando você usa Ctrl + Z ele para...

Comment: De fato tem um potencial problema ai: supondo que sejam feitas 100000 leituras, `vetor[i++]` vai acessar além dos limites do vetor alocado. Idealmente você também deve controlar que o valor de `i` seja menor do que o máximo no laço.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, o fim do input inserido por teclado é um **#EOF**, por isso que  pensei que o while seria encerrado quando se teclasse **enter** após digitar os números no console.

Comment: Hum... creio que se você digitar ENTER durante a leitura, resultará em uma string vazia cuja formatação com `"%li"` deve retornar 0. É diferente do CTRL+Z, que gera o `EOF`.

Comment: @Deyel Talvez seja bacana você editar a sua resposta para incluir a verificação dos limites do vetor no primeiro laço e para detalhar a questão do CTRL+Z. Sei que a resposta já ajudou o OP, mas não custa melhorar para qualquer outra pessoa que precisar no futuro. :)

Comment: Ou simplesmente parar o loop se a string for vazia.